# Child class is visible to attributes defined on parent class?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, attributes

```
[SomeAttribute(typeof(Child))]
public sealed class Parent
{
    public sealed class Child
    {
    }
}
```

How is this possible? Will it break something inside the implementation of the attribute? I'm only nesting Child because I'm sticking to the one class per file rule. If Child was defined outside I wouldn't need to worry about breaking the attribute with some infinite loop.

Comment: The type-resolution here is relative to the thing being decorated; so `typeof(Child)` is in the context of "as part of `Parent`", which could obviously just use `Child` (not `Parent.Child`). Is that what you mean? I don't have an actual language reference, note - I'm just describing the behavior.

Comment: @MarcGravell It compiles fine even if I make Child private.

Comment: that is fine; `Parent` can still see `Child`; again, it is resolved *relative to the context of `Parent`*

Comment: But typeof(Child) is being passed to some external attribute class which can't access child. I think it will fail at runtime if it's private since the attribute will not be able to do anything with the type information of a private class.

Comment: the attribute only sees `Type`, which it has full access to; indeed, strictly speaking the attribute itself is just metadata - it doesn't do *anything* until someone explicitly materializes the attribute (a form of reflection). There is nothing whatsoever privileged about a `Type` instance, even if it represents a private type.

Comment: Yes, but this attribute definitely needs to use stuff defined inside the type.

Comment: so? it asked for a `Type`, it got given a `Type`. The only way it can work from there is via reflection, and once you're at that level it has access to anything it wants, subject to the sandbox / security model. In most cases, it will have 100% access to `Child` even if `Child` is `private`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> How is this possible?

It's all to do with the visibility of the class. Your `Child` class is within the same assembly so the `SomeAttribute` will still have access to it (regardless if it's internal/private etc).

Will it break something inside the implementation of the attribute?

No

> I am only nesting `Child` because i'm sticking to the one class per file rule.

Technically you *aren't* sticking to the 1 class per file rule then, as there are now 2 classes (regardless if it's nested or not). Usually you would nest a class if it's an implementation detail of the outer class, which I gather in your case it's not.

If `Child` is a public class then put it in it's own unit, your example of nesting here isn't gaining you anything nor does it make any sense. If the `Child` class *should* be tightly coupled to the `Parent` class and used purely internally to it then it should be marked as `internal` or `private`.

Comment: +1 for recommending against public nested types. -1 for not answering the actual question.

Comment: Child is a class that contains validation rules specific to Parent and the attribute is actually [Validator(typeof(Child))] which applies the rules to parent. That's why I didn't want it in a separate file and it's far easier to maintain in the same file.

Comment: It still compiles fine if I make Child private.

Comment: @Kurian *"far easier to maintain in the same file*" - that's subjective I would argue it's easier to maintain if it's in it's own file, in VS you can even group files together.

Comment: @James Child is merely an informative class specific to the implementation of Parent that's used by the Validator attribute to validate parent. Should it really be in a separate file since it's completely dependent on the definition of Parent?

Comment: If that's the case then it *should* be a nested class, so no it shouldn't be in it's own file. However, you had it as a publically accessible class nested inside another class - which didn't make sense.

Comment: @James If I mark it as private, then it would compile fine since only a typeof(Child) is being passed to the Validator attribute. But internally the Validator attribute would not be able to instantiate the Child class based on the type since it's not public. The Validator attribute is from another assembly altogether.

Comment: @Kurian Ah well therein lies the problem. In my opinion, your `Child` class needs to be public as it's being instantiated by an external class and therefore *isn't* purely just an implementation detail of `Parent`. If it truly was, there would be no need for an external instantiation of the object, it would be created internally by `Parent`.